# Вариации готовых товаров WordPress/WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, интернет-магазин

Имеется 3 товара (допустим):
"iPhone XR 64GB, Красный",
"iPhone XR 64GB, Синий",
"iPhone XR 64GB, Белый".
Надо, чтобы в карточке товара можно было добавить список:"красный, синий, белый". Может кто-нибудь знает какое-нибудь готовое решение?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вариативные товары

Comment: Не вариант. Товары уже наполнены, они все созданы отдельными товарами и их много + под каждый товар надо отдельную страницу

Comment: Значит переделывай. Иначе это: находясь в Рязани, хочу половить рыбку на Мальдивах, но перемещаться "не вариант"..

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что мне не нужны вариативные товары. Мне надо чтобы каждый товар был отдельной страницей, но была внутренняя перелинковка между моделями с разными цветами. Если мне не надо было отдельными страницами делать, то я бы и не писал сюда, а сразу начал переделывать их вариативными.